# Returning PDF as FileContentResult from byte array produces invalid file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need a link for downloading or viewing a pdf in the browser. I tried almost every solution but after downloading the pdf file, the file seems broken.

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult DownloadKalite(Guid oid)
{
    string contentType = "application/pdf";
    List<KaliteDokumanlari> kalite = db.KaliteDokumanlari.Where(a => a.Oid == oid && a.GCRecord == null).ToList();

    string filename = kalite.Select(y => y.FileData.FileName).FirstOrDefault();
    byte[] filearray = kalite.Select(y => y.FileData.Content).FirstOrDefault();
     
    return File(filearray, contentType, filename);
}
```

My download link in view:

```
<div id="panel3d">
    @foreach (var doc in item.KaliteDokumanlari)
    {
        <div>
           @Html.ActionLink(doc.FileData.FileName, "DownloadKalite", new { @oid = doc.Oid })
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

After download pdf seems ok
[PDF Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt6No.png)

Comment: Suggestion: If you store PDF file in a directory and Save its path into Database it will be easier for you to manage files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I understand my problem. I created database with xaf . And xaf stored bytes as composed. Now it is working, I decompose bytes

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the byte into a MemoryStream

```
var pdfStream= new MemoryStream();    
pdfStream.Write(filearray , 0, filearray .Length);  
pdfStream.Position = 0; 

return File(pdfStream, contentType, filename);
```

If this does not work store the pdf as base64 string to avoid byte loss.

Comment: Still same with memory stream. Pdf could not open. And I should not change database column type cause this database in use by another project .

Comment: Can you provide how you store those bytes. Thats what is causing you trouble.